# What does "你什么都不是" mean?

Tags: translation

Literal translation:

你 - You
什么 - what / who / something / anything
都 - entire / all
不是 - blame

My guess - It's all your fault?

Comment: Similar expression: 你算哪根葱.

Comment: Your main misconception here is that 不是 means ‘blame’. It does not. 不 means ‘not’ and 是 means ‘to be’. In other words, [you] [anything] [entirely/at all] [not] [are] is a verbatim translation that should make it clear how this means ‘You are nothing at all’.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Literally: you are nothing at all, usually used in a disparaging way from what I can gather.  It follows the common pattern of Sub+什么都不+Verb, meaning that the subject verbs nothing at all.  Ex: 我什么都不知道 = I don't know anything.

Answer (score 4):

Simple translate: You are nothing.

Comment: Actually, I learn this word from World of Warcraft. While the 4th boss (Deathbringer Saurfang) of Icecrown Citadel (ICC), he will say "You are nothing" to a player who been killed. And if you are played a Chinese version, you will see a text "你什么都不是" while hearing such a sad voice. hah

Answer (score 1):

you are a nobody .我是中国人 我知道答案。告诉你们了

Comment: Can you expand on that and give a more semantic explanation?

Comment: @deutschZuid Allow me to explain. IMHO, _You are a nobody._ is a better translation than _You are nothing._ _Person_ is implied in 什么. I agree that the OP of this answer is somewhat impolite. He probably deserves the downvote. But, his answer is the most correct one here.(I am also a Chinese.)

Comment: "You are nobody" would be more idiomatic in English. 'A nobody' sounds very strange to my ears. Anyway, I was trying to encourage the guy to expand on his answer. I am fully aware what he meant.

Answer (score 1):

你什么都不是actually means"you are nothing,what right do you have to do this?",it's usually used when you quarrel with someone you despise because he/she is snooty or stupid,it's sort of rude,a more common expression is 你算什么东西 or 你他妈算什么东西,i suggest that you'd better not say 你什么都不是，你算什么东西 or 你他妈算什么东西 unless you wanna give someone a lesson,because they are expressions in a rude way,but if you hear someone says that to you，it implies he/she is not friendly to you.Sometimes you may hear someone say "你什么都不是" to himself,it probably means he blames himself  because he does something stupid.

Answer (score 1):

你什么都不是。  You are not anything at all.

你 you

什么 what (using the extending meaning "anything" here)

都 at all

不是 *not*, an auxiliary word means negative

Answer (score 0):

it's mean “You are a waste”  but it is more tactfully。Don't be serious occasion to say this sentence, it is considered an insult or hurt. For example: meeting, break up
------------------------------You would think that this would be that, but it's true. In addition, I talk with Baidu Chinese translation (search engine a Chinese common) translated into English in released, may be because of social philosophy and misunderstanding, please forgive me

Comment: Online translation engines do not translate text very well. This answer is almost completely unintelligible. And “You are a waste” is a different sentiment from 你什么都不是.

Answer (score -1):

means:
you suck!you are nothing!